# Send Email Notification if service is Stopped

Tags: powershell

Working on this script to get email notification when 1 or more services are not running.

something is wrong here, it sends:
**System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController is running**

```
 $service=Get-Service "VSS"
    if ($Service.Status -ne "Running") {
    $Body ="$service is not running"
    }
    else {
      $Body = "$service is running "
    }

    $From = "email"
    $To = "emails"
    $SMTPServer = "smtp"
    $SMTPPort = "587"
    $Username = "email"
    $Password = "password"
    $Body =$body
    $Subject = "$computer$ status"
    $smtp = New-Object System.Net.Mail.SmtpClient($SMTPServer, $SMTPPort);
    $smtp.EnableSSL = $false
    $smtp.Credentials = New-Object System.Net.NetworkCredential($Username, $Password);
    $smtp.Send($From, $To, $subject, $body); 
    $computer = $env:computername
```

Comment: What version of PoSH?  Have you tried inserting literals in place of your variables to make sure you can send at all..to yourself?  If you are 3.0 or higher try using Send-MailMessage instead.

Comment: receiving email is fine the problem is with script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if your question is, why it returns `system.something` instead of your service name, it is because
`$service` is not just the Name of the Service, it's the whole information of the service, that's why it returns `System.ServiceProcess.ServiceController` insted of `VSS`. refer to the Service Name:

```
$service = Get-Service "VSS" 
if ($Service.Status -ne "Running") { 
    $Body = "$($service.name) is not running" 
} else { 
    $Body = "$($service.name) is running " 
}
```

Comment: $service = Get-Service VSS | select Displayname, status  how about this?

Comment: @Owl no, i would not do this since you still would have to declare the name in a seperate variable to get it into the `$Body` string. it should work with my code above

Comment: If your concern is having to create another variable just to store the name, you can do the following to pull out a property of an object within a string:

`$Body ="$($servicename.Name) is not running"`

Comment: @Windos you're absolutely right, updated my answer

Comment: No Guys $service = Get-Service VSS | select Displayname this works perfectly for me. Don't want to break head anymore.

Comment: @Owl if you use `$service = Get-Service VSS | select Displayname` you can't access the `$service.status`  property since it doesn't exist, so your `if` will always be `false` and your body will always be `vss is running`. I'd use the code above, the only thing you have to do is to copy paste it ;-). But I can't force you to do it, so in the end do what you prefer. but how you do it now is wrong.

Comment: Oww this is More Cool $service = Get-Service "VSS" 
if ($Service.Status -ne "Running") { 
    $Body ="$($service.DisplayName) is not running Please start it." 
} else { 
    $Body = "$($service.DisplayName) is running Everything is Cool."

Comment: tried adding multiple services doesn't works here

Comment: Tried adding Multiple services Cool $service = Get-Service "VSS", "EBO", "Mysql" if ($Service.Status -ne "Running") { $Body ="$($service.DisplayName) is not running Please start it." } else { $Body = "$($service.DisplayName) is running Everything is Cool." 

unfortunately did'nt worked it sends only last service status update.

Comment: you have to use `foreach()` to achieve this. but this is a different question than the one you asked, so please ask it as a new question on Stackoverflow.

Comment: Need your help just missing something

$service = Get-Service ("VSS","msiserver","W32Time")




if ($Service.Status -ne "Running") { 
  ForEach ($Service in $sservice) {$service}  $Body ="$($service.DisplayName) is not running Please start it." 
} else { 
    ForEach ($Service in $sservice) {$service} $Body = "$($service.DisplayName) is running Everything is Cool." 
}